# R Optimize linear equations coefficients with constraints

Tags: r, optimization, package, linear-equation

Say I have `n` linear equations of the form:

`ax1 + bx2 + cx3 = y1
-ax1 + bx2 + cx3 = y2
-ax1 -bx2 + cx3 = y3`

Here is `n=3` and `a,b,c` are known and fixed.

I'm looking for the optimal values for `x1,x2,x3` such that their ranges are within `[-r,r]` for some positive `r` and the sum `sum(y1,y2,y3)` is maximized.

Is there a package for R which can handle such optimization problems?

Comment: The easiest option is using `library(gurobi)`

Comment: @MFR: is there a free version available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `optim` in R function for this purpose.

If you are trying to maximize `sum(y1,y2,y3)`, this actually simplifies the problem to maximize `(ax1 + bx2 + 3*cx3)` such that `x1,x2,x3 ∈ [-r,r]`

You can use below code to find the optimal values. Note that the `optim` function minimizes by default, so I am returning the negative value of the sum in the function.

```
max_sum <- function(x){ 
  a <- 2; b<- -3; c<-2;
  y <- a*x[1]+b*x[2]+3*c*x[3]
  return( -1*y ) }

r <- 5
optim(par=c(0,0,0), max_sum,lower= (-1*r),upper = r)

$par
[1]  5 -5  5
```

Comment: Thank, exactly what I need.